# Error: error unmarshaling Envelope: unexpected EOF

Tags: node.js, yaml, hyperledger-fabric

I am creating hyperledger fabric project. I am trying to make all peers join the channel. I entered in CLI peer and now when I am entering the "peer channel create -o orderer.example-network.com:7050 -c examplechannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx" I am getting this error "Error: error unmarshaling Envelope: unexpected EOF". Can anybody help me sorting this out?

All docker containers are running perfectly and are up. Docker compose files are in yaml format.

Answer (score 0):

This situation is happened due to bad envelope byte array.

Please create the genesis.block & channel.tx properly and also pass the -tls --cafile of orderer with  "peer channel create" command if needed.